# How to use quotes in nested PHP->JS->HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to figure out how i can use quotes in a third "layer".
Do i need to "escape" the quotes somehow?

**PHP/JS/HTML**

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
    echo "$('#rImgObjNr').text('Bilder: ".$imgDirs[$randomDir]."<i class='fa'></i>');";
echo "</script>";
```

It's my icon element that has problems with it's quotes:
`<i class='fa'></i>`

When i use  `'`I "close" JS text.. and if i use `"` i close the PHP.
How can i solve this?
Can i use my HTML element inside of this PHP/JS text?

Comment: To escape quotes and achieve a nested quotes just use `\"` as in `"your\"string\""` which would output `your"string"`. This works in Php and Js

Comment: Try escaping like `<i class=\'fa\'>`

Comment: ok, it worked, but it wasn't the whole answear. I had to change `.text`to `.html`also.

Comment: Try next time with [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php). I think is easier with nested quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to change `.text`to `.html` and then escape the quotes like `\"`.

**CODE**

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
  echo "$('#rImgObjNr').html('Bilder: ".$imgDirs[$randomDir]."<i class=\"fa\"></i>');";
echo "</script>";
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape your double quotes by prepending backslash.
Replace your code like this below.

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
    echo "$('#rImgObjNr').text('Bilder: ".$imgDirs[$randomDir]."<i class=\"fa\"></i>');";
echo "</script>";
```

Answer (score 1):

May be it work :

```html
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $('#rImgObjNr').text("Bilder: <?php echo $imgDirs[$randomDir];?><i class='fa'></i>");
</script>
```